# Show that: $(D_v f)(p)\in \mathbb{R}$ is max iff $v=\alpha(\nabla f)(p)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $ \alpha > 0$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be open and $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable.

Let $p \in U$ with $(\nabla f)(p)\neq0$. Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^m$ with $|v|=1$.

Show that: $(D_v f)(p)\in \mathbb{R}$ is max iff $v=\alpha(\nabla f)(p)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $ \alpha > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz you have that $$(D_vf)(p) = \nabla f(p)^\top v \leq \lvert \nabla f(p) \rvert \lvert v \rvert = \lvert \nabla f(p) \rvert$$ for all $v$ with $\lvert v \rvert$. So  $\lvert \nabla f(p) \rvert$ is an upper bound for our problem. You have equality iff $v = \frac{\nabla f(p)}{\lvert \nabla f(p) \rvert}$.

One can also consider the [Lagrange-Multiplier-Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$D_{\mathbf{u}}f=\frac{\nabla f \boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{u}}{\Vert \mathbf{u} \Vert}$$